# How to view CPU model in red hat vps or cloud

Tags: redhat, central-processing-unit

How can I view CPU model in Red Hat VPS or cloud? If I run the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo` as root it shows `qemu virtual cpu version (cpu64-rhel6)`

How to view model? Like E3-xxxx or v5-xxxx.

Comment: The argument against doing this is very similar to *browser detection*. Attempting to identify CPUs is taking a step back from investigating the features or metrics you actually care about.

Answer (score 2):

You can't: your VPS doesn't have direct access to any physical processor, but to a virtual processor provided by the QEMU hypervisor. This allows moving the VM images between hosts having different kind of processors as it can emulate the same CPUs through *dynamic binary translation*.

How to know the model? Ask your service provider. Does it matter? Not really, since you won't run into any compatibility issues, as you must only have compatibility against the emulated processor.